# Azure Data Factory V2: Optional parameters

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm using ADFv2 and I would like to use some optional parameters defined at the dataset level. I didn't found if that can be achieved.

If I define a parameter in the dataset (after defining a parameter at the pipeline level and connecting the two so the pipeline passes the value to the parameter at the dataset level) when I run the pipeline manually and don't specify a value I get the error

```
No value provided for Parameter 'parameter'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just for anyone that may be looking to do something like this. At least until today's date we can't have optional parameters for a pipeline, this is by design according to what the Product Team of ADF has told me through a support ticket in Azure.

Answer (score 13):

Try `@coalesce(null)` as the expression for the parameter.

Comment: can confirm this works, it also clearly indicates the parameter input is 'empty'

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this issue recently and the answers provided here, didn't quite address my needs. The way that we are using the ADF pipelines relies on the parameter to be set if you need to run it manually or if being run by a trigger, to be empty so that they can be dynamically set to the date/time that the trigger was activated.

In our pipeline we have checks like the following.

```
@if(empty(string(pipeline().parameters.FolderDate)),
formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyyMMdd'),
pipeline().parameters.FolderDate)
```

It turns out that if you provide the parameter as a lowercase null, then my pipeline works as expected.

[image: ADF Parameter Setting]

Answer (score 2):

We have a dataset for blob csv files.  The dataset has the filename parameterised, as well as the container and directory.

[image]

When this dataset is a sink, we might want to specify the file to write to, or leave it blank and let Azure provide data_xxxx.csv filenames for us.

When this dataset is a source, we might want to specify which file to open, or leave it blank to use the wildcard option (all csv in the directory).

In that limited sense, we want the filename parameter to be optional.

But you can't leave the dataset parameter field blank in the UI or the pipeline won't compile (validate).

[image][image]

In those cases where we want the filename to be blank we use the trick suggested above to inject an empty string (we use `@coalesce(pipeline().parameters.filename,''`) and leave the filename parameter empty when triggering the pipeline.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `@coalesce` you can use `?` like `@dataset()?.fileName` if empty return null.
"defaultValue": you can fill `@null` or `[]` or better `@''`. Data Factory and Synapse Analytics cross pass parameters need some input to validate pipeline.

[Null Values Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mTjI.png)

[If Null return null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYxDo.png)

Answer (score 1):

@fgbaezp, this is a late answer but you can assign an empty string to a parameter by using dynamic content, something like @toLower('')

Comment: As stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions), using curly brackets when defining dynamic parameters convert the latter as string. For example : @{pipeline.parameters.myNullableParameter}

Answer (score 0):

What would you expected if you don't specify a value for the parameter? 
If you have a default value for that parameter, you could specify default value when defining a parameter. 
`"parameters": {
            "parameter1": {
                "type": "String",
                "defaultValue": "defaultValue1"
            }
        }`

Comment: I would expect that the value would be null or non-existing. My use case right now is using an optional "suffix" for the name of the data that the ADF stores. Ex: "savedData{suffix}". I know that I can use a default value for the parameter but that's not ideal for me.

Comment: why not give default value “”, it means empty string. And I think it can also be null.

Comment: Already tried that but when I run the pipeline if I don't specify a value for the parameter ADF throws me the following error:
    No value provided for Parameter 'parameter'

Comment: Are you using portal or SDK or powershell? Could you share your pipeline and dataset json? At least the parameters related part.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround for this is using coalesce in dynamic content and leaving the parameter blank.

ex: **@coalesce(pipeline().parameters.parametername,'') in dynamic content**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#coalesce

[image]